# connect c++ object signal to QML signal handler with enum parameter

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have the following c++ plugin code:

```
class NetworkManager : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

...
enum WIFIStat{
    STAT_NOTINITED,
    STAT_INITED
};
Q_ENUM(WIFIStat)

 Q_PROPERTY(WIFIStat wifiStatus READ wifiStatus NOTIFY wifiStatusChanged)
```

and i want  to connect to a signal handler in QML:

```
signal wifiStatusChanged(WIFIStat wifiStatus);

onWifiStatusChanged: {
    console.log(wifiStatus)
}

Component.onCompleted: {
   network_manager.wifiStatusChanged.connect(wifiStatusChanged);
}
```

but i'm getting the follwing error:

```
Invalid signal parameter type: WIFIStat
```

How can i define the enum `NetworkManager::WIFIStat`  type parameter int the handler function?

Comment: It seems to be an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089196/how-to-access-c-enum-from-qml

Comment: if i put signal wifiStatusChanged(NetworkManager.WIFIStat wifiStatus); i get: error: Unexpected token "."

Comment: Ok. Now it is clear what was the problem with that. I read the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using var in my handler function parameter:

```
signal wifiStatusChanged(var wifiStatus);
```

but i ended up using another approach as stated here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29202462/2614418

```
Connections{
    target: network_manager
    onWifiStatusChanged: {
        console.log("Status:"+wifiStatus)
    }
}
```