# QDir::SortFlag memebers available in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qdir

How can be made available the members of QDir::SortFlag to a QML script?
For instance, how to fill up a combo from a QML script with the members of QDir::SortFlag enum or QDir::SortFlags in order to choose some sort criterium?
Is this available through some C++ custom enum in a custom class only?

Comment: Have you looked into `FolderListModel`? Maybe not exactly what you ask, but related and perhaps usable in some other way (the flags are available as boolean properties)

Comment: Thank you, but I need more than that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access C++ enum from QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089196/how-to-access-c-enum-from-qml)

Comment: Yes and no. I was interested in the fact that some QT enum, already existing and not defined by me, is accessible by design. Seemingly not, although I was expecting that. Eventually, that article solution is a technical answer to my question, but I have knew that approach and thus I have referred to this kind of technique as "custom calss or enum". It's overkill, IMHO, a good subject of a feature request to QT, at least for the enums.